# Json Parsin in android

Tags: java, android, web-services, text-parsing

http://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/Services.aspx?service=getStatutesTabNews

This is my web service. I want to parse it and I want show news_id and news title. Please post, showing me how to parse it so that I can store all the values in a string. I tried but am getting `Exception ..`

```
try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/Services.aspx?service=getStatutesTabNews");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"),8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
        String line="0";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }


//  String name;
    try
    {
        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json_data=null;
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

//              name=json_data.getString("name");
            map.put("id",  String.valueOf(json_data.getString("news_id")));

            map.put("title",json_data.getString("news_title"));
            map.put("shortdescription",json_data.getString("news_short_description"));
            map.put("date",json_data.getString("news_date"));
            mylist.add(map);
        }


    }
        catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: show your exception in your question that may help

Comment: also can you put your json string here.

Comment: http://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/Services.aspx?service=getStatutesTabNews

Comment: please to parsing of this url

Comment: for this will refer you to check this example first http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());

Comment: If hope ur issue is solved with @Herry link , if not pls share ur issue ..

Comment: Error in http connectionjava.net.UnknownHostException

Comment: Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException these two exception coming

Comment: I think your are not seen my answer. you are getting UnknownHostException because you do not declare internet permission in manifest, getting NullPointerException because result value is null. So please see my answer and I am sure for your solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse using **Gson parser**.
So first download **gson-1.1.jar** file from http://findjar.com/jar/com/google/code/gson/gson/1.1/gson-1.1.jar.html

and then add jar file into your project build path then use the below code for parsing (Simple replace your parsing code with below code)

```
  try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/Services.aspx?service=getStatutesTabNews");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String  data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<NewsData>>(){}.getType();
        List<NewsData> details = gson.fromJson(data, collectionType);
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Log.i("error","error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

bean for above code is

```
public class NewsData
{
    private String news_id = null;
    private String news_title = null;
    private String news_short_description = null; 
    private String news_date = null;

    public String getNews_id()
    {
        return news_id;
    }
    public void setNews_id(String newsId)
    {
        news_id = newsId;
    }
    public String getNews_title()
    {
        return news_title;
    }
    public void setNews_title(String newsTitle)
    {
        news_title = newsTitle;
    }
    public String getNews_short_description()
    {
        return news_short_description;
    }
    public void setNews_short_description(String newsShortDescription)
    {
        news_short_description = newsShortDescription;
    }
    public String getNews_date()
    {
        return news_date;
    }
    public void setNews_date(String newsDate)
    {
        news_date = newsDate;
    }
}
```

and add internet permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

if you still not get your result you can use below code .

```
static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static JSONArray jsonArray=null;
    static String json = "";



mJsonArray=getJSONFromUrl(url);
        try{
        JSONObject mJsonObject=null;
        for(int i =0;i<mJsonArray.length();i++){
            if(!mJsonArray.isNull(i)){
                 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 mJsonObject=mJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                 map.put("title",mJsonObject.getString("news_title"));
                 map.put("shortdescription",mJsonObject.getString("news_short_description"));
                 map.put("date",mJsonObject.getString("news_date"));
            //add you map in to list
            }
        }
        }catch(JSONException jexc){
            jexc.printStackTrace();
        }




public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

          // Making HTTP request
          try {
              // defaultHttpClient
              DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
              HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

              HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
              HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
              is = httpEntity.getContent();            

          } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          try {
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                      is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              String line = null;
              while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb.append(line + "\n");
              }
              is.close();
              json = sb.toString();
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
          }

          // try parse the string to a JSON object
          try {
            jsonArray =new JSONArray(json);
          } catch (JSONException e) {
              Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
          }

          // return JSON String
          return jsonArray;

      }
```